# pbbt and import python files

Tags: python, integration-testing, black-box-testing

I want to use `pbbt` (Pluggable Black-Box Testing toolkit) for testing. Let's suppose I have that structure:

```
├──black_box_tests
│   ├──black_box_settings.py
│   ├──input.yaml
```

and I want to import `black_box_settings` in yaml:

```
py: |
  import black_box_settings
```

I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'black_box_settings'` when try run `pbbt input.yaml output.yaml --train` command. There is no example of importing your own modules on the [documentation page](https://pypi.org/project/pbbt/).